# UITableView separator issue in Simulator

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios-simulator

A simple code is made in Objective-C like showing some data in a tableView. But when I run the code in iPhone 6 plus/7 Plus, separators are missing and while scrolling its like flashing. I don't know about the real device.
I tried to find a solution and I found that changing native resolution will help me.But I don't know how to do. Can anyone guide me step by step?
Or any solution?

[image]

Comment: It is related to LED screen resolution, since actual devices has very high resolution, the Monitor finds it hard to render those minute lines on the screen. It will work fine on actual device.

Comment: You shouldn't care about it. When you run on real device, it's fine.

Comment: Thank you sir, i was in panic to see wheres my fault? many many thanks sir.

Comment: Set the simulator scaling to 100%, you will see all lines. Just hit Command + 1.

Answer (score 1):

Not an issue!

Your code will execute perfectly on the real device.

Comment: is not a answer,plz move your answer to comment section

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue.

UITableView separator is shown in your simulator.

If your simulator was zoomed out means that will not visible thickness. You can zoom in your simulator and check it. (click to zoom Window + 1)

In Real devices, the separator will defiantly show.

Comment: in zoomed view separator is showing but its flashing while scrolling

Comment: You can check on real devices. It’s work work perfectly. 